# Android build.gradle (Module: app) conflict with firebase and play-services dependencies

Tags: android, firebase

I'm using the following dependencies:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.0.1'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.1.1'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:1.1.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
```

In the Gradle file an error is shown:

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version
>   specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found
>   versions 25.3.0, 25.1.0, 24.0.0......

I can't update

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1
```

because i get the following error:

> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the
>   google-services plugin (information about the latest version is
>   available at
>   https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/)
>   or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 10.0.1.

When i remove the Firebase dependencies the error is gone. What causes this error and how can i get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:10.0.1` library has transitive dependencies on:

```
com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.1.0
com.android.support:customtabs:25.1.0
```

You can force use of a newer version by explicitly including it in your dependencies:

```
compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.0"
compile "com.android.support:customtabs:25.3.0"
```

The other version listed in the warning message, 24.0.0, must be from the Play Services library.  In Android Studio, you can open the Gradle window and double-click on *:app > Tasks > android > androidDependencies* to get a dependency report to find the conflicting libraries.

I would also strongly recommend replacing:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
```

with the specific APIs you need. They are listed [here in Table 1](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup).  Including the single `play-services` library pulls in ALL the APIs, needlessly increasing the size of your APK and frequently requiring Multidex.

See this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42374151/4815718) for further discussion of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

did you add the `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:version·` to the dependencies and the `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` to the build.gradle ?
and change the `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.0'` by `com.android.support:support-v7:25.3.0'`