# Gradle dependencies version

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, firebaseui

Hi should i be worried about this gradle warning/error?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.bananasandpajamas.pilloclock"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1' <---- THIS ONE
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.1'
    //compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.1'
    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:1.2.0'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

It's giving me a warning that there are two versions of android.support:appcompat.
But when i tried to downgrade it to 25.1.1. It gives me warning that i should use the latest one.

edit:

> Error message : All com.android.support libraries must use the exact
>   same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime
>   crashes). Found versions 25.3.1, 25.1.1. Examples include
>   com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.3.1 and
>   com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.1.1

Comment: See this answer to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43004082/4815718

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your build version is `buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"`

and your dependencie version is

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
```

How it will compile ?

Change your version in appcompat version or update your android studio..

Comment: I don't know why but its compiling and my android studio is updated.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it has something to do with firebaseUI, i think its outdated.

Comment: i had the same problem ... when i updated it problem solved so i suggest this idea

Comment: Yee i ended up using older version of appcompat (25.1.1). Thank you. :P.